# Scroll content of fixed element along with parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

Question title might be bit confusing, but please have a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/p3sLv/2/) fiddle for more info.

I have a container with scrollbar and one element fixed left to it. When I am scrolling I would like to make fixed element `content` also scrolling. Here is the code

```
 $('.parent').on('scroll', function(){
   var top = $(this).scrollTop(), _top = $('.right').offset().top;
   $('.left').animate({
      scrollTop : top - _top
   },0)
 });
```

Please refer to [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p3sLv/2/) for demo.

This is working but there is some non uniform scrolling and I am unable to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the extra subtraction of _top is causing the uniformity issue, since it is recalculating the offset top each time, and continually subtracting it.

```
$('.parent').on('scroll', function(){
    var top = $(this).scrollTop(), _top = $('.right').offset().top;
    $('.left').animate({
        scrollTop : top
    },0)
});
```

Appears to let the scrolling be more uniform, minus some padding issues.